# Java: Check if a Key is contained in two HashMap

Tags: java, search, hashmap, key

Is there a way to search and get a subset of keys that are contained in two `HashMap` objects?

Until now I have always made an iteration from a hashmap and looking for matches in the second.

I just wanted to know if there was a smarter way to do this comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
List<String> listOne = new ArrayList<String>(mapOne.keySet());
List<String> listTwo = new ArrayList<String>(mapTwo.keySet());

List<String> listThree = new ArrayList<String>(listTwo);
listThree.retainAll(listOne);
```

Or
 [Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/CollectionUtils.html#intersection%28java.lang.Iterable,%20java.lang.Iterable%29)

```
CollectionUtils.intersection(java.util.Collection a, java.util.Collection b)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do that in a complexity less than O(N). The only thing you can do, is to iterate the smallest hashmap.
Another thing you could do is to use the key sets of the hashmaps and use the method `retainAll`, which perform the intersection for you, but the complexity doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

Use a HashSet. If your use case needs to have (key, value) pairs, then maintain a HashMap and a HashSet both, and whenever a key is inserted in the HashMap, insert it in the HashSet as well. Otherwise, just maintain a HashSet.

Then you can use retainAll() function to find the intersection of the two sets.

```
HashSet intersection = hashSet1.retainAll(hashSet2);
```

The time complexity will be O(n) amortised. This is almost the same as that of what you are doing, but this would make your code much cleaner and readable.

Note that you can maintain a List instead of Set and call the retainAll() method of list. However, retainAll() of List will run in O(n^2) complexity, because the contains() method of List runs in O(n) whereas contains() of HashSet runs in O(1) amortised.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `newMap` by removing all keys using `removeAll` as shown below with inlin comments:

```
Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<>();
Set<Entry<String, String>> set1 = map1.entrySet();//get the entries from Map1
set1.removeAll(map2.entrySet());/remove all matched entries mateched in map2

Map<String, String> newMap = set1.stream().//convert set1 to Map using stream
    collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue));
```

This example uses `Map<String, String>`, but can be applied to any types (of course for custom classes, you need to override `equals()` and `hashcode()` methods from `java.lang.Object`).

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most efficient way to do it, but this Java 8 one-liner works

```
Map<Integer,Integer> mapA = ..... // your first map
Map<Integer,Integer> mapB = ..... // your second map
List<Integer> keys = mapA.entrySet().stream().filter((v) -> mapB.containsKey(v.getKey()))
                         .map(v -> v.getKey()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```